# Cannot get assembly name for "obj\iPhone\Debug\MyApp.iOS.exe". Could not load file or assembly The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

Cannot get assembly name for "obj\iPhone\Debug\MyApp.iOS.exe". Could not load file or assembly 'MyApp.iOS.exe' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Fail to build IOS app, exe is missing in directory

we have already cleaned and rebuild multiple times...

We would like the build to succeed and launch the app on the ios device

Comment: Did you try clean building your app on the basis of dependency!?

Comment: Are you using the Stable visual studio? Try to delete the obj and bin folder. Any steps to reproduce this problem?

Comment: @G.hakim Yes we already tried this.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Apparently we had a problem about our Xamarin ios  version which was not the correct, VS19 is supposed to upgrade automatically the sdk to 12.6 but it didn't yesterday. There was an update about it this morning. Thanks !

Comment: So the problem solved by this updating?